# Twitter update with media with request.js

Tags: node.js, twitter

I am trying to post a update_with_media on twitter with node.js and request.js. I would like to post the image base64 encode:

```
    var request = require('request');
    var r = request.post({
       url: "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update_with_media.json",
       oauth: {
           consumer_key: '...',
           consumer_secret: '...',
           token: '...',
           token_secret: '...'
       }
    }, function(err, response, body) {
       return console.log(err, body);
    });
    var form = r.form();
    form.append("status", "Test...");
    form.append("media[]", "...");
```

Unfortunately I get an Error: '{"errors":[{"code":189,"message":"Error creating status."}]}'
Before I tried to post a normal update without an image. This worked fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Having a look at [adaline / twitter_update_with_media.coffee](https://gist.github.com/adaline/7363853) helped:
The working solution looks like:

```
  var buffer = new Buffer(imageData, 'base64');     

  var r = request.post({
     url: "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update_with_media.json",

     oauth: {
        consumer_key: '...',
        consumer_secret: '...',
        token: '...',
        token_secret: '...'
     }
  }, function(err, response, body) {
     return console.log(err, body);
  });
  var form = r.form();
  form.append('status', "TEST...");
  form.append('media[]', buffer);
```